# Код одного цвета в файле sass в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

Весь код одного цвета и не работает подстановка кода, например при написании tac после нажатия enter вместо text-align: center останется tac. В html и css всё работает, сам код написанный в sass работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

@KoVadim
[image: Сасс синтаксис установил]

[image: Тут ничего]

Установил этот плагин, больше ничего найти не могу, ничего не поменялось что я сделал не так или надо как-то настроить ?

Comment: Расширение файла точно правильное? Никакой кириллицы? Для него настроено использование установленого расширения VS?

Comment: да расширение правильное (можно на скринах увидеть) кириллицы нет.
Как настроить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все потому, что похоже у Вас нет плагина для подсветки синтаксиса sass.

Зайдите в Market Place (прям в редакторе слева есть иконка в виде квардратиков) и напишите там "sass syntax highlighting", Вам покажет несколько вариантов плагинов для подсветки синтаксиса. Почитайте и выберите тот, который понравился/имеет хорошие отзывы. После этого скорее всего сразу все заведется сразу. Если нет, внизу справа найдите надпись "plain text", нажмите туда и выберите там sass.

Также рекомендую поискать линтер для sass, что бы было легче в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки ноутбука появились настройки в плагине, настроил и всё заработало.
До этого когда заходил в настройки плагина там было пусто, как всегда большинство проблем лечится перезагрузкой